# How to include a table multiple times in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading

Here is my query, using EntityFramework 6.0

```
                 var x = context.Student
                .Include(d => d.Class.Select(di => di.Teachers).Select(i => i.Subjects))
                .Include(d => d.Class.Select(di => di.Teachers).Select(di => di.Marks))
                .firstOrDefault();
```

Entities Subject and Class are childern of Teachers entity. How to include both the child entities in one query?
When the query is executed, does the Teachers entity will be loaded twice?
As the 'class' table is included twice, when the SQL is generated does it joins the 'class' table 2 times?

Comment: checked the generated query in sql profiler, it didn't join the tables twice. So Include doesn't create duplicate joins

Answer (score 2):

Are you using EF6 or EF Core? On EF Core you can use ThenInclude to load deeper level entities. Like (from MS Docs):

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .ThenInclude(author => author.Photo)
        .Include(blog => blog.Owner)
        .ThenInclude(owner => owner.Photo)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: its with EF 6.0

Comment: Then you're doing this quite right. Don't worry about duplicate joins. The provider should be smart enough not to do that. Example from MS Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading

Comment: As mentioned above, don‘t worry about duplications. `Include` Is just instruction what to load and there exists deduplication logic.